# Isn't double[][] equivalent to **double?

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm asking this because my program have two functions to multiply matrices, they multiply only 4x4 and 4x1 matrices. The headers are:

```
 double** mult4x1(double **m1, double **m2);
 double** mult4x4(double **m1, double **m2);
```

They do m1*m2 and return it in a **double, below is a snippet of 4x4 multiplication.

```
 double** mult4x4(double **m1, double **m2){
      double** result = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           result[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
      }
      ...multiply...
      return result;
 }
```

The difference between mult4x1 and mult4x4 are only in the indexes used inside them.

I have these 3 matrices:

```
double m1[4][4] = {
    {2, 3, 5, 6},
    {9, 8, 1, 7},
    {5, 4, 3, 1},
    {7, 6, 1, 2}
};

double m2[4][4] = {
    {1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1}
};

double m3[4][1] = {
    {2},
    {3},
    {3},
    {1}
};
```

Trying to multiply these matrices an error occurs.

```
double** test = mult4x4(m1, m2);
double** test2 = mult4x1(identity4x4(), m3);
//identity4x4() creates a 4x4 identity matrix - double** identity4x4();
```

Yields:

> error: cannot convert `double (*)[4]' to`double**' for argument `1' to`double** mult4x4(double**, double**)'
>
> error: cannot convert `double (*)[1]' to`double**' for argument `2' to`double** mult4x1(double**, double**)'

Isn't double[][] supposed to be equal to **double? An array of arrays of double.
Any clarifications, misconceptions and errors are welcome.

Comment: `double**` is a *pointer to a pointer to `double`*, not a 2D array.

Comment: This isn't `C++`.  As far as I can see, this is all just plain `C`.  A `C++` programmer would probably use `vector`. (at least until such time as they were very comfortable with pointers, if they had a really good reason to switch to pointers)

Comment: Your first malloc is incorrect.  You should call `malloc(sizeof(double*)*4);`

Comment: An array is not a pointer, and an array of arrays is not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Aaron McDaid, i'm c++ beginner and have a little baggage of classes that used c in school.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for pointing that out. I realized the mistake just now.

Comment: @user1493813: That's unfortunate, because C++ has more reliable ways to do this. E.g. `std::array<T, 4>` really is an array of 4 elements of type `T`, even in the case where T itself is an array: `std::array<std::array<double, 4>, 4>`. That array behaves like a proper 2D array.

Comment: @molbdnilo Although they may be conceptually different, they have interchangeable syntaxes. that is, `a[2]` is the same as `*(a+8)`(assuming 32-bit pointers, could do it more generally).

Comment: There is no reason to use (non-smart) pointers in C++ unless you are writing libraries.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No.
A `double**` is a pointer to a pointer to a double (`double*`).

So actually it should be created like this (note the extra * in the first malloc sizeof()):

```
  double** result = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*)*4);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       result[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
  }
```

So in memory it would look like this:

```
[] -> { d,d,d,d }
[] -> { d,d,d,d }
[] -> { d,d,d,d }
[] -> { d,d,d,d }
```

There are 4 buffers that hold 4 doubles, but are not continuous.

While your double[4][4] is a continuous buffer in memory, like this:

```
 { { d,d,d,d } { d,d,d,d } {d,d,d,d} {d,d,d,d} }
```

Comment: The visual part clearly helped to understand the difference between the two declarations.

Comment: @user1493813 The best i could do with brackets:)

Answer (score 24):

Although both `double[N][M]` and `double**` let you deal with 2D arrays, the two are definitely not equivalent: the former represents a 2D array of `double`s, while the later represents a pointer to pointer to double, which can be *interpreted* (with the help of convenient square bracket syntax of C/C++) as an array of pointers to `double`, or as an array of arrays of `double`.

The `double[N][M]` represents 2D arrays of "rectangular" shape, while `double**` lets you build "free-form" (jagged) arrays by allocating different amounts of memory to each row of your matrix.

The difference to the compiler is that given `double[N][M]` and a pair of integers `{r,c}` it can compute the location of the element by computing the offset from the origin of the array, without reading anything from the memory. Given a `double**`, however, the compiler must compute the address of the pointer to a row, read that pointer, and only then compute the address of the target element. Because of this difference, the two are not interchangeable.

Comment: wow, never thought about the jagged arrays (different amount on each row), living and learning.

Comment: "array of pointers to pointers to doubles."  Should the word 'array' be dropped from the front?  This sounds like a three-dimensional array.

Answer (score 3):

There is no type `[][]`. What you have is in fact `m2` which is an array of arrays of size 4 of type double and `m1` which is an array of arrays of size 1. An array of arrays of size 4 is not equivalent to double pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Well I hope I will not turn out stupid here but the notation `double [][]` is also used when you are addressing a continuous block of memory, while `double**` is not necessarily continuous.

I think that is the reason behind the error. Even though you can use the same semantics to access values, they are actually different types.

Answer (score 2):

[][] is not equivalent to **; 
`double ** var;` is a pointer of pointers and as you can see from your allocation in memory you hold an array of pointers and each pointer inside points to an array of values of `double`

`double var [4][4];` is held in memory in on place, and it is somewhat equivalent to double *; In this case the knows the size of the matrix ( 4 x 4 ) so when you use `var[2][2]`, for example, it know where is that located in memory; `var[x][y]` translates to something like this: `var[x + y * 4]` and the declaration can be interpreted as `double var [16];`

Raxvan.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. `double[n][m]` allocates a single block of memory big enough for your two dimensional array. You then get the convenience of not having to calculate your own indexing. When passing a two dimensional array to a function, the compiler requires you to give the size of the inner dimension so that it can work out the indexing.

`double**` is a pointer to a pointer. Since C allows pointer arithmetic, it may mean an array of pointers, where each pointer points iself to an array of doubles. The values themselves need not reside in a contiguous block of memory.  As you can see they are quite different beasts.

If you have a `double[n][m]` and want to pass it to a `double **` you will need to construct your own indexing array.

Answer (score 2):

No... `m1` is an array with four elements, each of which is an array of four elements. Same with `m2`. Even if the first "level" decays from an array into a pointer, the second "level" won't. The question is why? Let's look at some code:

```
/* double[4][4] implicitly converts to double(*)[4]
 * giving you a pointer to first element of m1 so
 * you get back an array of four doubles.
 */
double (*pm1a)[4] = m1[0];

/* This isn't right, but let's pretend that it was
 * and that what you got back was a pointer
 * to a pointer that pointed to m1 properly.
 */
double **pm1b = (double **)m1[0];
```

So, what would happen with our hypothetical code if we were to do `pm1a[1]` and `pm1b[1]`?

`pm1a[1]` is fine: it would *correctly* advance `pm1a` by `4 * sizeof(double)` (since the pointer points to `double[4]`).

`pm1b[1]`, on the other hand, would break: it would advance by the wrong amount: the size of a pointer to a double.

But this isn't all. There's a more subtle bug still. If both dimensions were to decay, the compiler could not know that an *array* is being accessed. It will happily interpret `pm1b[1]` as a *pointer* to a double. And then what happens? It will take whatever `double` *value* is stored at that location and treat it as a *pointer* to a `double`.

You can see why this would be a disaster.

Comment: The word 'pointing' in the first sentence might be confusing, as there is no pointer involved.  The contents of `m1` are integers, and arrays thereof, but there is no pointer value inside `m1`.  We can ask for the address of `m1`, or even the address of *parts* of `m1`, but `m1` doesn't contain any addresses.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah poor choice of words. I'll reword.

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is that you can not make double to point to any other memory address if you declare it as double[][] ( Something like final field )

But if you declare it as **double, then it can point to any memory location.

Answer (score 1):

No they definitely are not equivalent the former represents a 2D array of doubles while as latter represents a pointer to pointer to double.