# Pointer, Struct, and Function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm learning about pointer and dynamic array in C, but I'm not clear about pointer in C.  I would appreciated if anyone could verify my understanding of the following codes based on the below information:

```
/*Struct*/
typedef struct {
   int *pInt;    
}newStruct

/*Functions*/
newStruct *createMyStruct() {  
   //codes
}

void printNewStruct(newStruct *pStruct) {
   //codes
}
```

Please verify:

1. `int *pInt`: this is an array of type int that's in the struct
2. `newStruct *createMyStruct`:  a function that's named `createMyStruct`. `createMyStruct` is a pointer that points to `newStruct` and create a copy of the `newStruct`.
3. `newStruct *pStruct`: `pStruct` is the same as `createMyStruct` (?)

Question:
1) When I use `malloc` in a function (e.g. `createMyStruct` function from above code) to allocate memory, where would I have to free this memory?  Inside the function itself or in `main`? If in `main`, why in `main`?  I thought the memory has to be freed right away after it has been used.

My apology if my above statements aren't clear...I'm still really confuse about pointer and `malloc`.  Please verify/explain in simple terms for a Newbie.

Comment: [Nice basic Pointer Tutorial](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)

Comment: @VusP- Thank you for the link!  Do you have another link that give examples for pointers that deal with struct and function.  I'm still confuse about pointers involve struct and function.  It would be create if the link have complete codes and explanations.  Thanks again!

Comment: [I hope you find this useful](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap12/subsection2.1.1.4.html)

Comment: [and this perhaps](http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=282)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's try to clarify this:
1) `int *pInt` is a pointer to an Integer. This MAY point to the first value of an array, but it doesn't have to.
2) `newStruct *createMyStruct()` is a function that has a return value of a pointer to a newStruct structure. Most likely you want to `malloc` in this function and have it return the pointer.
3) `newStruct *pStruct` means that the input parameter for this function is a pointer to a newStruct structure, in this case named pStruct (I assume you know how to handle parameters in C)

As for your question: It kinda depends on when you no longer need the memory allocated. If you were to `free` it in the `createMyStruct()` function, you would basically return a pointer to an invalid location (causing undefined behaviour if you try to dereference it). Generally you should `free` the memory you allocated only when you are completely sure you no longer require whatever you allocated. You can either do it in your `main` or write your own function which you call.

Comment: "*This MAY be the first value of an array*" No, it may **point** to the first value of an array, if the address of one had been assigend to it.

Comment: 2) "...return the pointer" - by this, do you mean "return createMyStruct"?

Comment: No, `createMyStruct` is the name of the function. Somewhere in that function you create a pointer (something like `newStruct *tmp` and then later `return tmp`) which is your return value

Comment: "*basically return a pointer to an invalid location (causing undefined behaviour).*" Just returning a pointer to deallocated memory does **not** cause undefined behaviour, but **dereferencing** it would.

Answer (score 1):

1 - if you `malloc` memory, you have to free it. It doesn't matter where. You should do it when you are no longer using the memory. It doesn't have to be immediately, but you should probably do it when you know you can, otherwise you have to remember to free it later.

You said

> I thought the memory has to be freed right away after it has been used.

That's just advice. But it's very good advice. You could never free it, and keep using memory. You might run out of memory or your program might crash. C will not help you, the best thing you can do is stick to advice.

That's vague advice, but only you, the programmer, know the best place to do it. It's not easy, but memory management isn't easy.

2 - You need to remember how big the array is, because C will not check if you `malloc(3)` but access `struct.pInt[4]`. You could store this size as a variable in the struct.

Comment: Do you have tips on how to keep track of malloc to free it later?

Comment: @user2925557: There are no tips, you allocate the memory, it's your job to free it at the right moment. If you don't free it, you're not doing your job. It's that simple.

Comment: Do you of any good website that have practice exercises with answers and explanations for freeing allocated memory?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not going to give you a 1on1 pointer guide (I'm not planning to write a book), but here's the quick guide, based on your assumptions/questions:

- *"`int *pInt`: this is an array of type int that's in the struct"*

It Might be, `pInt` is a pointer to an integer. It needn't be an array. <strike>An array *is* a pointer, but a pointer isn't always an array</strike>. Right, an array is -of course- an array, but the way you access it in C is through *either* an array variable or a pointer. 
The differences are [clearly explained here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html)

Basically: an array is a continuous block of memory, an array variable often (well, always save for 3 cases listed on the page I linked to above) decays into a pointer. Read the why's and how's, to get a clear understanding of the differences and similarities between pointers and arrays.

If you understand why one of the following snippets is not allowed and the other one is, you're there:

```
char *str = "Read only";
printf("%c\n", str[2]);//prints a from (0=>r, 1=>e, 3=> a...)
str[2] = 'q';//ILLEGAL
//BUT:
char str[] = "Read only";
str[2] = 'q';//perfectly legal...
printf("%c\n", str[2]);//prints q!
```

Why is this? Simple. In both cases, the literall `"Read only"` is stored in read-only memory. The difference is that, by assigning this string to a pointer(`char *str`), we're assigning the read-only mem address to the variable, so we can't change the memory it points to (that's what read-only means).
In the second case, the string literal is stored in the same read-only memory, but because we're assigning it to an array, it's values are copied to newly allocated stack memory, and we *can* write to that.

So, a pointer *points* to some chunk of data in memory. This memory can be writable or not, the memory address could be the address of part of an array or it could be a single int (like it is in your case), You could even have pointers that point to several pointers, and each of these pointers could, essentially, point to different places in memory (ie not a continuous block).
Anyway, consider this:

```
int i = 123;
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};//array
int *iPtr = &i;//iPtr contains the mem address of i
printf("%d\n", *iPtr);//prints 123
iPtr = arr;//iPtr points to the same as arr (note no & operator)
printf("%d\n", *iPtr);//prints 1
//now probably a mindfuck for you now, but:
printf("%d\n", *(iPtr+1));//prints 2!
```

The last bit is just to show what pointers are: it's a location in memory, big enough to accomodate an `int`, so if I take that space in memory, and do `+1`, I'm accessing that chunk of memory right next to the one my pointer points to. In memory, this might look something like this:

```
| 0x0f0 |   0x0f2  |  0x0f4   |  0x0f6   | //mem address
| *iPtr | iPtr + 1 | iPtr + 2 | iPtr + 3 | //access via pointer
```

That's why pointers *can* be dangerous. In the code above, `iPtr` points to the first of 3 ints (as defined in the `arr` array), but if I access `*(iPtr+4)`, I'm accessing memory that is out of bounds. You are accessing memory that was not claimed/initialized, or owned by something else. This can, and probably *will* lead to unexpected behaviour... but I have seen this used to get some extra randomization...

- *"`newStruct *createMyStruct`:  a function that's named createMyStruct. createMyStruct is a pointer that points to newStruct and create a copy of the newStruct."*

You lost me here, this is a function definition. The function is indeed called `createMyStruct`, and it returns a pointer to something of the type `newStruct`. That's it, just like `int some_function()` is a function that returns an int

- *"`newStruct *pStruct`: pStruct is the same as createMyStruct (?)"*

No, `pStruct` is a pointer to a `newStruct`, and `pStruct` is a function argument, not a function, which `createMyStruct` is.

On calling free:

You call `free` on variables that are stored in memory allocated from the heap, when you don't need them anymore. If they go out of scope, you can't free them anymore, so you have to dellocate the memory when you still have a variable that points to it, but you shouldn't deallocate anything you might need later on in the program:

```
char *str = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
free(str);
//I can't use str here anymore
```

But:

```
int main()
{
    void some_function();
    some_function();
    //I can't free str here, mem-leak immanent!
   return 0;
}
void some_function()
{
    char *str = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
    //do stuff, but no calls to free
}
```

in this case, `free(str);` should have been the last statement in `some_function`. If `some_function` would've been `char *some_function()` and we'd have written this:

```
int main()
{
    char *return_val = NULL;
    char *some_function();
    return_val = some_function();
    printf("%s was returned by some_function\n", return_val);
    //the allocated memory is accessible here
    //And it has to be freed before main returns, so:
    free(return_val);//deallocate!
    return 0;
}
char *some_function()
{
    char *str = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
    //do stuff, but no calls to free
    return str;//return char pointer
}
```

it ended with `return str`, then you'd have to call `free` in the `main` function, as it has a pointer to the allocated memory.

That's it, in a nutshell...

Comment: Why would there be a memory leak in main?

Comment: @user2925557: because `main` cals `some_function`, and that function allocates heap memory, but fails to free it. The `main` function has no pointer to that allocated memory, so it can't free that memory either. The memory is allocated, but never freed, so it sits there, marked as _"being used by another process"_. That's why there's a leak.

Comment: @alk: no it's an example of how you can access memory out of bonds using pointers

Comment: @kotlomoy: true, I will correct this, but what I wanted to say was that an array variable works, sort of, like a ptr. They are similar. I didn't want to go into too much detail, so there are some omissions in my answer, like exit, and how it deallocates heap memory...

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636809/isnt-double-equivalent-to-double. This is everyday type of question. People are confused between arrays and pointers because some bad guys told them that "An array is a pointer". You are one of those bad guys.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: No no, `*iPtr+4` does not access `iPtr` out of bounds, but it dereferences `iPtr` and adds `4`.

Comment: @alk: Changed it to `*(iPtr+1)`. I wrote this answer yesterday after a long day at the office, so it is packed with falsities and omissions. If I find the time today, I'll read through it again, and try to correct as much as I can...

Comment: @kotlomoy: Sorry for that, I've made some edits now. I know there's still a lot left unsaid, and that the information is far from complete, but like I said: I'm not going to write a comprehensive guide to pointers here. But the fact remains: I have written a falsity, you were right on that. There's still a lot more to be said here (on mem management in general, and pointers in particular) but future OP's questions will doubtlessly arrive...

Comment: Much better now but you still do not have clear picture. "..an array variable holds the memory address of the first element in that array. It points to the first element in it." - no. Sorry for pedantry but this part still looks confusing. Array variable doesn't hold any address in the same way as `int` variable doesn't hold own address. What you probably want to say is that array variable *decays* to pointer in most cases.

Comment: @kotlomoy: Exactly... that's what I was trying to say. I initially wrote that it decays into a pointer, save for 3 cases (char[] literal, & operator and sizeof). I'll edit once more). Don't be sorry for _"pedantry"_. I've said before that if ever there were to be a "pedantic" badge, I'd probably be one of the first to get it. You were right, I wasn't. If you hadn't down-voted me, I wouldn't have set about searching for a clear explanation and wouldn't have found the page I linked to, so thank you. I use pointers, and gotten used to them. At least now I understand their quirks better.

Comment: @kotlomoy: Thanks, both for undoing the -1, and taking the time of reading my answer, and pointing out the omissions and faults in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. int *pInt - it's just a pointer to some possibly existing array (there's no space to put data in, it could point later to some place in memory to be used as array of ints, if you set it)
2. newStruct *createMyStruct: a function that's named createMyStruct.
   This is correct.

   ```
   createMyStruct is a pointer that points to newStruct and create a copy of the newStruct
   ```

   No, it's the pointer to the function (or the function name), but the function returns a pointer (newStruct*) to your structure, if you implement the function right you'll get allocated and initialized structure ready to use
3. newStruct *pStruct - it's not the same as createMyStruct, pStruct will be uninitialized pointer,createMyStruct is your function

Here is how you would use your structure and methods:

```
int main()
{
    newStruct *pStruct = NULL; // nothing there yet
    pStruct = createMyStruct();
    if(pStruct==NULL) { printf("error"); }
    pStruct->pInt[0] = 123;
    ...
    free(pStruct->pInt); // you have to free the array in your struct too
    free(pStruct);
    return 0;
}
```

If you're wondering where to put the free, look at the example main function... The pStruct is declared and initialized at the beginning of main and free'd at it's end. For the most of the time, it's sufficient to free the memory at the same level (function) you did originally allocate it.